# DNS does not resolve on certain ISPs

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy, mobile-devices

We are currently in the process of building a cloud service and we are having DNS issues.

DNS **is resolving correctly** via
 - Cellular/LTE/Verizon
 - Wifi/Cable (tested with different ISPs)

DNS **is not** resolving via cellular/LTE/AT&T

**Edit**: Problem occurs with iPhone on AT&T/LTE. Verizon works fine, also on iPhone. The problem was reproduced with Chrome + Safari, also after flushing the DNS cache (airplane mode on + off). Chrome on iOS shows the error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, Safari shows not detailed information.

**Edit 2**: I unfortunately can't share uncensored DNS settings but perhaps that helps (these settings have been up for over a week and the TTLs have not been changed):

```
A   @   <censored ip 1> 600 seconds
A   sub1    <censored ip 2> 1 Hour
A   sub2    <censored ip 2> 1 Hour
CNAME   ftp @   1 Hour
CNAME   issue   @   1 Hour
CNAME   mail    @   1 Hour
CNAME   smtp    @   1 Hour
CNAME   sub3    @   1 Hour
CNAME   www @   1 Hour
CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com 1 Hour  Edit
MX  @   mail.domain.tld (Priority: 0)   1 Hour  Edit
MX  @   smtp.domain.tld (Priority: 10)  1 Hour  Edit
TXT @   google-site-verification=<censored key> 1 Hour  Edit
TXT @   v=spf1 a mx ip4:<censored ip1> ~all 1 Hour  Edit
TXT selector._domainkey k=rsa; p=<censored key> 1 Hour  Edit
TXT _domainkey  o=~; r=noreply@truerec.io   1 Hour  Edit
NS  @   ns47.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour  
NS  @   ns48.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour
```

Do we need to add more name servers or is it a different issue?

Comment: We cannot troubleshoot this issue without knowing the (unredacted) name of the DNS record you are experiencing trouble with. There several possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I know that sucks, but I'm currently not authorized (yet) to publish the uncensored DNS or IP.

Comment: What was the TTL _before_ you made the changes? You will need to wait at least that long before DNS caches expire.

Comment: Good point, but we did not change the TTLs. It's been roughly a week since the settings have been set up this way.

Comment: Aside from suggesting that you use a tool such as [dnsviz](http://dnsviz.net/) to troubleshoot your domain for an invalid DNSSEC configuration (a common cause of inconsistent responses between ISPs), it is unlikely that we can provide further assistance without that level of detail.

Comment: I don't see any problem. I would suggest doing further DNS lookups on the AT&T network and see if you can figure out what they are doing wrong.

Comment: Yep, sorry I can't provide further details. It suddenly works again now after many times of retrying. Tested with a cleared DNS cache. We experienced similar issues before with people trying to open the web site from different countries.

Answer (score 0):

It started working again after many, many times of retrying (closing all tabs, browsers, restarting the affected mobile devices, airplane mode on & off). I can't give any further explanation. Perhaps an issue with AT&T.

Comment: Local issue, not the carrier.